# How to speed up edit-compile-test cycle in AOSP?

Tags: android-source

I followed https://source.android.com/setup/start. It mostly worked, except that I needed to modify acloud to work on my Arch Linux system and pass it `--launch-args='-vm_manager=qemu_cli'` because the default VM manager of Cuttlefish (crosvm) crashes on my system.

I make changes inside `frameworks/opt/vcard`. Running `atest AndroidVCardTests` inside that directory takes 3:17 if a file was changed since the last run and 1:53 if no file was changed. This makes edit-compile-test cycles very slow. Is there a way to speed this up?

When running the command while no emulator is running, it aborts after 0:47. It seems like most of the time is spent installing the tests on the device. The tests itself seem to be fast (it reports a few ms of time for each test).

Because it’s slow even if no file was changed, I think that most the rest of the time is spent finding out which files need to be recompiled. However, I know that I only changed files inside `frameworks/opt/vcard`.